# Remove whitespace before [quote-tag and after [/quote]

Tags: python, regex, string, newline

I need to remove whitespaces/newlines from a string but only before a [quote-tag and after a [/quote]. Other whitespaces/newlines should be untouched.

Example:

```
[quote=lorem]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut aliquam elit, nec lobortis neque.[/quote]

Nunc ultrices, eros a fringilla varius, metus arcu rutrum libero, quis pulvinar sapien lorem et mauris. Nullam vitae nisi tristique, congue ipsum ut, lobortis augue.

Nam tempus justo hendrerit, feugiat ipsum eget, pellentesque eros. Fusce vel pretium felis, nec euismod nisl.








[quote=lipsum]Sed efficitur malesuada eleifend.[/quote]



Ut accumsan nulla sed lacus luctus, in venenatis diam tristique.
```

I want this to become:

```
[quote=lorem]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ut aliquam elit, nec lobortis neque.[/quote]
Nunc ultrices, eros a fringilla varius, metus arcu rutrum libero, quis pulvinar sapien lorem et mauris. Nullam vitae nisi tristique, congue ipsum ut, lobortis augue.

Nam tempus justo hendrerit, feugiat ipsum eget, pellentesque eros. Fusce vel pretium felis, nec euismod nisl.
[quote=lipsum]Sed efficitur malesuada eleifend.[/quote]
Ut accumsan nulla sed lacus luctus, in venenatis diam tristique.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify it by running the replacement in 2 rounds:

First round: `\n+\[quote` and replace it with `[quote`

Second round: `quote\]\n+` and replace it with `quote\]`

I hope this helps you :)

You might strengthen the matching for tabs and spaces too, like so: `[\n\t\s]+`

Example:

```
newString = re.sub(r'[\n\t\s]+\[quote', '[quote', quoteString, re.S)
newString = re.sub(r'quote\][\n\t\s]+', 'quote]', newString, re.S)
```

..or even just wrap them around each other

Comment: Thank you. A question: How do I add a newline in the replace in the first round?

Comment: Before the [quote tag. Something like \n[quote but that doesnt work?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[\n\t\s]+\[quote', '\n[quote', quoteString, re.S)` should work fine. It doesn't on your side?

Comment: Weird, now it did work. Must have done something wrong. Thanks again!